# How to check if date exists in table and if it does update only?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have tmpCompensation that contains some data imported from some source. The file contains information including customernumber and deliverydate. If table Compensation contains the same customernumber with same deliverydate then I just need to update the row. Otherwise, insert a new row.
The problem is that for customer 7865343 the row is updated but also a new row is added as it compares also the date 2017-03-04 with the date in the tmp table and since the date is different it also adds a new row with the date 2020-12-10. This shouldn't happen as 2020-12-10 for that customer exists in Compensation table so it should only update the row in Compensation.
How can I achieve this?

```
The resultset after the update/insert should be as follows in the
 compensation table
7865343, 2020-12-10,'bike','087543'  
 7865343, 2017-03-04,'home','864380'  
95345, 2018-12-10,'home','864380'
95345, 2019-12-10,'home','864383'
Thanks


    create table tmpCompensation (customerNumber int, deliveryDate varchar (20), deliveryMethod varchar(50), recid bigint)
  create table Compensation (customerNumber int, deliveryDate varchar (20), deliveryMethod varchar(50), recid bigint)

  insert into tmpCompensation  select 434353, 2020-10-10,'bike','76756454' union
    select 7865343, 2020-12-10,'bike','087543' union
    select 95345, 2019-12-10,'home','864380' 
    
    insert into Compensation  select 434353, 2020-10-10,'bike','76756454' union
    select 7865343, 2020-12-10,'car','087543' union
    select 7865343, 2017-03-04,'home','864380' union
    select 95345, 2018-12-10,'home','864383'
```

Comment: What you are describing is an "upsert" or `MERGE`; there are plenty of examples of these. What didn't you understand about the examples you looked at?

Comment: Let's start by identifying the primary keys of both tables, as well as any other unique indexes and constraints. And you have 2 rows for 7865343 - so what should the row (or rows) in your actual table look like for that customer after this process?

Comment: side note: `2020-12-10` isn't a date, it's an int. specifically, 1998. `'2020-12-10'` is a string representation of a date, but since you're working with `DateTime` you should be either using `'20201210'` or `2020-12-10T00:00:00'` as your string representation of a date to ensure that the date will always be correct regardless of the culture settings. Note that `DateTime2` and `Date` data types don't have this bug.

Comment: Yea the date fields are actually varchar. I assume the primary key is the recid but the tables in the db for some reason don't have primary keys. I think the tables were poorly build. The fields that need to be used to identify if the data already exists in the main table are customernumber and deliverydate.

Comment: " the date fields are actually varchar" That's the worst possible way to store a date. If you need a date, use the `Date` data type. If you need a date and time, use `DateTime2`. If you need local (time zone aware) dates use `DateTimeOffset`.